# Change hostname in hyperlinks in email generated by Atlassian Confluence

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-proxy-ajp, confluence

I have an instance of Atlassian Confluence fronted by Apache using mod_proxy_ajp to pass inbound port 80 requests to 8080 on tomcat.  Let's say the url users use is http://www.mywiki.com/confluence/.  Confluence generates emails to send to users with links to pages with changes.  When a user clicks on links in those emails, the user is taken directly to the local server hostname with :8080, not the public facing DNS name that Apache accepts requests from.

In other words, the links are http://nasty-app-server-name:8080/confluence/xyz/ and not http://www.mywiki.com/confluence/xyz.

How can I configure Confluence to insert www.mywiki.com in the hyperlinks generated by Confluence, instead of the nasty-app-server-name?  I figure somewhere there's a template that has $hostname.  I want to override that with a DNS name.

Comment: And I found the answer myself.  The setting to change this is "Server Base Url" under General Settings in the Admin left menu.

Comment: +1 for posting the answer, although it's better if you post an actual answer and accept it - that way this question won't come up in the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I found the answer myself. The setting to change this is "Server Base Url" under General Settings in the Admin left menu.